# Is it possible to create a view in one database from another database in oracle when databases are different machine?

Tags: oracle, view

Lets say I have a oracle database db1(actually user)  in machine **A**
and another database db2 in machine **B**. Is it possible to create view in 
db2 from db1.If possible how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by using database links. For example, in db2:

```
create database link db1_link connect to myuser identified by mypassword using 'db1';
create view myview as select * from mytable@db1link;
select * from myview;
```

Where `using 'db1'` refers to a TNS entry, but it could be replaced with the actual TNS descriptor.